# How to use string resource files only from localized folder?

Tags: android, android-resources

There is russian app that won't be localized, but plurals in russian not same as in english, so if system language is russian - everything is OK, but if system language is not russian (for example english) - so there goes a problem... How can I use resources only from folder "values-ru" when system language is not russian?

Comment: Why you use locale specific folder, if you don't want to localize app?

Comment: The problem is that if system language is for example english, so plurals used like in english language (plurals in english and russian languages are different).

Comment: If you don't want to localize app - rename folder `values-ru` into `values`

Answer (score 0):

```
String localLanguage = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();

        if (localLanguage.equals("eng")){
            Locale locale = new Locale("eng");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }else {
            Locale locale = new Locale("ru");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
```

Change App language according default language ..!

i hope it's useful to you...!